# Better to use multiple email address fields or 1 field for invites?

Tags: forms, input-fields, email

I am working on an interface that asks the user to add 5 or more email addresses. The invite email that gets sent is the same for all invitees. Is it better to use 1 field for the user to add all the email addresses or multiple individual fields for each email?

Comment: Probably the biggest problem with one field is keeping the addresses separate (especially if the copy-paste something like `"Fred Bloggs" <fred.bloggs@example.com>`. If you _do_ go with one field, I'd probably make it a multi-line edit box and insist on one address per line.  Using _separate fields is probably cleaner still, but you then have to consider add/delete buttons etc.

Answer (score 5):

One input will be much user friendlier especially if this filed will instantly tokenize and validate the input as it is done in almost all email clients

[image]

Comment: This would be the way to do it, if you can manage it. To slightly simplify the processing, you could have a text-box where you enter _new_ email addresses, that on completion get added to the "To:" list as "boxed" entries as shown above.

Comment: This is basically how it works, inline input box without the border. Solution is tricky to implement, but [there are controls](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) one can adjust to save implementation time.

Answer (score 0):

Same as Jurijs, I would go with one field only. However, I'd use a `textarea`, clearly  explaining that each email should go on one line.

The reason for this is that is:

- simpler
- users probably have been exposed to this many times
- cleaner
- users will quickly understand what to do if they want to delete or modify a record.
- a 5 lines `textarea` will quickly transmit an affordance, which is more complex on single line fields
- scanning is really fast, as opposed to single line, or multiple lines with different fields

**From the stakeholder view, it's really easy to implement, just one field and that's it**. Having multiple lines will require controls for each field, and will have a way bigger friction. Not only you'll have a lot of control, but... what happens if the user wants to delete the 3rd field?

- *Will she think the 4th will move up?*
- *will she think she'll have to edit rather than delete?*

Simply put, you'd be leaving room for confusion, which means you'll lose time testing things that might not need any testing.

On the other hand, a single `textarea` will have very low friction, if any. Hence, my suggestion would be: **go with a `textarea` and one email per line.**